# Comparing data of single row with multiple rows

Tags: python, r, excel

I have data of about 400 students and need to analyze these giving inferences to individual student about their performances in respective subjects compared to other students.

[image: student data]

Students are in rows and subjects are in columns.
I am new to data science if anybody please can help me with this, i would be grateful.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example and your intended output when asking a question. Showing what you have tried so far would also help us understand your line of thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could compare the individual students to the whole sample by subtracting the `mean()` of the columns from the values.

Lets assume your `data.frame` in `R` looks like your example above, and every column besides the first two are subjects.

```
new.data <- cbind(old.data[1:2], 
                  as.data.frame(lapply(old.data[3:ncol(old.data)], 
                                function(x) {x - mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)})))
```

This should give you a new `data.frame` with the difference between the person's individual score and the overall score of the subject across all your students.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to achieve. If you have questions about statistics. This might be the wrong place to post the question. Try it around here :

https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Here is place to post technical issues. But for a strat try `summary()` on your data which gives you some standard parameters about your data. After it you could produce some histograms by using `hist()` and so on. Get yourself a book for R-Beginners and for Data Science beginners and play around with your data. After it you can come back with precise question either here or in the other forum.